# Raspberry pi python firebase-admin error:

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to use firebase-adin library on a raspberry pi 3B but the following error comes up all the time:

````
    from firebase_admin import firestore
  File "/home/pi/iSight/iSight-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure '
ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.```
````

Comment: did you install `google-cloud-firestore` in Python 3.7 ?

Comment: Yeah, i did but the error remains

Comment: so maybe you have two Pythons installed. And you installed module in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. If you run code with `python script.py` then you can use `python -m pip install ...` to install modules for this Python. You may also check versions `python -V` and `pip -V`. OR maybe you run code using `virtual environment` but you installed module without activating `virtual environment`

Comment: I'm using the same python and I have activated virtual environment but unfortunately the error remains

Comment: did you install it again with active virtual environment? Better use `python -m pip install ...` because `pip` may install for different version. And if you still have error then module is NOT installed.

Comment: I used the exact same method and nothing changed

Comment: did you use the same `python script.py` to run code? Maybe inside code use `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and use this path to install module - `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`.

Comment: I tried that as well but it still does not work